# The property 'LoadedBehavior' was not found in type 'MediaElement'

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, mediaelement

I tried to create a simple Store app.
Here is my XAML code:

```
<MediaElement Source="Untitled.wma" Name="myMediaElement" 
 Width="450" Height="250" LoadedBehavior="Manual" UnloadedBehavior="Stop" Stretch="Fill" 
 MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded"/>
```

I would control it from Button_click method but it doesn't work.

The errors I get are:
`The property 'LoadedBehavior' was not found in type 'MediaElement'.`

`The member "LoadedBehavior" is not recognized or is not accessible.`

`Unknown member 'LoadedBehavior' on element 'MediaElement'.`

Same for `UnloadedBehavior`.

I took this code from examples from [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: What's the problem, obviusly

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the wrong `MediaElement` help page. [`System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is part of .NET framework, in WinRT you're using [`Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.MediaElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement%28v=win.10%29.aspx).

As you can see in its help page, the latter doesn't have `LoadedBehavior` and `UnloadedBehavior` properties. If I guessed you're intentions correctly, you can achieve the same by setting `AutoPlay` property to `False`:

```
<MediaElement Source="Untitled.wma" Name="myMediaElement" 
              Width="450" Height="250" AutoPlay="False" Stretch="Fill" 
              MediaOpened="Element_MediaOpened" MediaEnded="Element_MediaEnded"/>
```